# Jquery button only firing click events intermittently in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a simple script that has a timer, and counts how many times the user hits a button since the timer was started. In my browser, it works great. In iOS (I'm using Appcelerator Titanium to render as a WebView), it's not registering each "click" event, only firing the event intermittently. It uses the JQuery and JQuery Mobile. Any help is appreciated.

Javascript:

```
var timer;
var hits = 0;
var bPlaying = false; //bool for playing / paused

function startTimer() {
    if ( bPlaying ) {
    tick();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#dstart").show();
    $("#dpause").hide();
    } else {
    hits = 0;
    timer = setInterval(tick, 100);
    $("#dstart").hide();
    $("#dpause").show();
    }
    bPlaying = !bPlaying;
}

function tick() { $("#score").html("Hits: " + hits); }

function mark() { ++hits; }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click( startTimer );
    $("#pause").click( startTimer );
    $("#mark").click( mark );
    $("#dpause").hide();
    $(".content").css( "margin-bottom", $("#score").outerHeight() );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="score"></div>
<span id="dstart"><input type="button" id="start" value="Start timer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" /></span>
<span id="dpause"><input type="button" id="pause" value="Stop timer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" /></span>
<span id="dmark"><input type="button" id="mark" value="Mark" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" /></span>
```